# htaccess from old joomla website to new custom made

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

we have just finished a new version of a website.
This time we have opted for a "bespoken" code that is going to replace the joomla version.

The joomla version is rather well indicized with google, with more than 1300 url stored by google.

We were thinking to go with htaccess 301 redirect to force visitors from old to new pages, but there is no correspondence between old pages and new ones.

What are the best practices in this case? Should we redirect everything to the new website index page? 
Wouldn't that be anti-SEO?

Is there a way to get all the old indicized urls and try to have "huge" htaccess that has a record for each old-new page pair?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT

If that helps, old urls are made like so: www.website.com/en/var/pagename/

while ne urls are www.website.com/newpagename/ or ending with html.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways for this:

1. **Developer Level**: You need to build a system plugin for new joomla! site for this.In a plugin, there should be a code that detect the variables and values from old url and based on that you can redirect a visitor to appropriate page having new url.
2. **Administration Level**: You can use the [sh404SEF Extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef) for new joomla! site which will provide you sef alias urls (add old urls as alias of new ulrs) as well as custom redirects.

Both options are good on point of usability.
Let me know if you find this helpful.

Thanks, 
Mrunal

Comment: The new site is not Joomla.

Comment: exactly: the new site is a custom cms. Thanks anyway